# How to build page not found in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm doing a project with vue 3 and I have a problem with generate a pageNOTfound. So, I'm going to show my code cause I can't see the problem.

Route.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import NotFound from "@/views/NotFound.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },

  {
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
    component: NotFound,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router"; // <---
// estilos app
import "./styles/styles.scss";

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

NotFound.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>404: Lo sentimos, la página que buscas no existe</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "NotFound",
};
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header />
    <div class="app-container">
      <Home />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppHeader from "@/components/AppHeader.vue";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AppHeader,
    Home,
    Footer,
  },
};
</script>
```

I can't see where is my problem cause pageNOTfound is not working at this time. I tried a lot of changes but I don't know how can it works.

Comment: I put: { path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", name: "NotFound", component: NotFound,}, on router.js. How I put NotFound on App.vue?

Comment: I did it but is not working......it says: 'NotFound' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: Which is your index.html? Where is your <router-view> tag?

Comment: What do you need to know about my index.html?

Comment: The <router-view> tag is missing inside the App.vue template. The div-tag with id=app should be in the index.html, not inside the App.vue template

Comment: I  will use it but notfound is still saying that is not defined

Comment: in my index.html there is a <div id="app"></div>. I tried to put router-view but is not working.

Comment: I took your NotFound component and your routes into my app. It works like a charm. It seems that your app is not functional.
Is the div-tag with id="app" in your index.html?
Do you import main.js in the index.html?
Did you remove the id="app" from the template in App.vue?
Is the <router-view></router-view> tag inside the App.vue template?
Better you edit your question and post the current files including the index.html

Comment: If you have a follow-up question then create a new one. You must not change the question so that the original answers won't match anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 404 as a completely seperate page, without footer and header, then you need these files:

#### App.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>
```

#### Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-header />
    <div class="app-container">
      ... other home content here ...
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppHeader from "@/components/AppHeader.vue";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    AppHeader,
    Footer,
  },
};
</script>
```

This way the `App.vue` does not contain header or footer, but the `Home.vue`. And the 404 page will be displayed without header and footer.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with your tips but is not working...

Comment: When you put the `<home /> ` component inside the `App.vue` and in addition there is a route to home and this will be displayed via the `router-view`, then you will see double content of `home`. You need to remove the `home`tag from the `App.vue`.
Second, as your 404 pager is a routed page, it will appear where the `router-view` tag is. Therefore, the 404 page will appear inside the template of the App, between header and footer.

Comment: So, I have to change, in app.vue, home to notfound? That is what you say?

Comment: I have edited my previous answer (see above)